# How can I create the database entities in a layered application

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-scaffolding

I have to create a layered .net core application including a database. I want to build the database entities with sql-first approach. The solution looks like this:

[image: Text]

All of the projects are class libaries, except the `FoodSupplementCompany.Program`.

My question is, how can I use `Scaffold-DbContext` to generate the entities to the `FoodSupplementCompany.Data` project?

Comment: Once you have the Database defined in SQL Server you can use the VS menu to add a DataSource and select the database.  The classes will automatically be created.

Comment: You already know the command. Is it really that hard to find how to use it?

Comment: Have a look at EF Core Power Tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the guide here states: [scaffold-dbcontext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/powershell#scaffold-dbcontext)

Example:

```
Scaffold-DbContext 
    "Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Blogging;Trusted_Connection=True;" 
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
    -OutputDir Models
```

`-OutputDir` -> The directory to put files in. Paths are relative to the project directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Package Manager Console:

```
cd .\FoodSupplementCompany.Data 
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold -s ..\FoodSupplementCompany.Program
```

The line `cd .\FoodSupplementCompany.Data` is for navigating into project directory where the `DBContext` is located.

And the line `-s ..\FoodSupplementCompany.Program` is for stating where is the startup project to use.